# How does my host know that I own my domain name?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, nameservers

I purchased my domain name from Namespace and am hosting my application on Digital Ocean. In order to point my domain name to my digital ocean droplet all I had to do is enter the digital ocean nameservers on Namespace then I was able to set my domain name on digital ocean. How does digital ocean know that I own that domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in your own question: you have access to the domain(/zone) nameservers configuration, so you're the owner (or at least you have some privileges over that domain)l

Comment: what would stop someone from entering my domain name for their application on digital ocean ?

Comment: the fact that the (real) domain name will not point to Digital Ocean, as only you (or the domain owner) can change records and nameservers for a domain/zone. So someone else *can* enter another domain in D.O., but it will be useless without the ability to change nameservers/records for that domain/zone.